# How to insert json within an array into highcharts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

I generate an array like so in php with json nested in the array under `chartData`:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:18 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "chart_title" => "A title"
    "chart_type" => "line"
    "chartData" => "[[1470406561000,2116],[1470406561000,2116],[1470406562000,2116]]"
  ]
]
```

I want access the `chartData` json within this array and insert it into a [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo) series.

I've tried using: 
`window['chart' + chartData.id].series[0].addPoint(chartData, true, shift);`

and also a `forEach` loop:

```
chartData.forEach(function(dataPoint){
                        console.log(dataPoint);
                        window['chart' + chartData.id].series[0].addPoint(dataPoint[0], true);
                         dataPoint.slice(0,30).forEach(function(point){
                             window['chart' + chartData.id].series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);
                         });
                    });
```

Both don't show any errors in the console and the values don't show up on the chart. If I `console.log(dataPoint);` I get what looks like the correct output:
`[[1470406561000,2116],[1470406561000,2116],[1470406562000,2116]]`

How would I insert the `chartData` json into a [highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo) series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was the JSON was not being parsed by jQuery on the view and essentially passing it to the highcharts series raw. By adding `jQuery.parseJSON(chartData);` It was able to parse correctly and display on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can try like this:

```
    var dataPoint =   [[1470406561000,2116],
                       [1470406561000,2116],
                       [1470406562000,2116]];  

    var chart = $('#chart2').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].setData(dataPoint);

    $('#chart2').highcharts().redraw();
```

Please make sure you change chart id i.e. `#chart2` correctly as per your code.

Comment: Thanks @vijayP I tried this works without any issue if I set the dataPoint var in jquery but if I try to set it using using the array like var `dataPoint = chartData;` It draws the chart like so http://oi68.tinypic.com/29djria.jpg

Comment: image you posted is not accessible to me as of now. can you `console.log(chartData)` before statement `dataPoint = chartData;` and check it.

Comment: I console.logged the data and the output is `[[1470406561000,2116],[1470406561000,2116],[1470406562000,2116]]`

Comment: its same as other one right...? any error in console? Logically it should work.

Comment: Yeah it looks the same, Only when I console log `var dataPoint =   [[1470406561000,2116];`. The output is `[Array[2]]
0:Array[2]0:14704065610001:2116length:2__proto__:Array[0]` vs when I output `dataPoint = chartData;` the output is `[[1470406561000,2116]]` not sure why its processing differently.

Comment: can you please check the `typeof` of `chartData`? it should be an Array and not any other one.

Comment: Added `jQuery.parseJSON(chartData);` and that fixed it. Thanks for your help Vijay